# Multilingual typesetting difficulties in local Tex Live compared to Overleaf

Tags: xetex, babel, overleaf

I was usually using Overleaf with Xelatex backend to write my documents and I never had any issue. Lately, I mainly focused on writing using a local Tex Live installation and I can't properly produce documents with greek and english.

To start off, the code

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{fontspec}
\usepackage[english, greek]{babel}
\usepackage{noto}

\begin{document}

Γειά. Hello.

\end{document}
```

works normally in Overleaf but in the local TexLive it produces: `. Ηελλο.`

I have tried multiple preamble configurations I found online to use both languages but I can't seem to manage to be able to utilize them as I was used to in Overleaf. More specifically

1. I could type text in both languages without having the english appear in greek characters like "hello" appearing as "ηελλο". Now I seem to have to use the `/foreignlanguage` command.
2. I can't just use the babel and the fontspec packages to write in both languages without any hassle.

Overleaf uses TeX Live, why do I have these inconsistencies? How is it possible for the same code to produce different results? How can I use both languages on my local installation normally?

The log file is [here](https://pastebin.com/vNeTmzST).

Comment: I can't reproduce the problem, and with both xetex and luatex I'm getting “Γειά. Hello.” Please, post the `log` file.

Comment: @JavierBezos I added the log file. The same behaviour happens in two PCs, one with Ubuntu and one with Lubuntu.

Comment: you are using an older texlive where greek switches to the grmn font, and then you get "There is no Γ in font grmn1000!" Can you update? Newer version of greek behave better here.

Comment: @Adam, I cannot reproduce the problem, either. The tex compiles successfully with xelatex and lualatex. Perhaps you want to upgrade your Tex Live distribution to the latest version?

Comment: I installed it a week ago, I guess the repositories have an older version. I will update it, but would an older version create so many and serious issues?

Comment: linux systems often have outdated texlive live. A vanilla texlive should say texlive 2021. And greek had problems then, I even sent a bug report about this to the maintainer some times ago.

Comment: Thank you all, I will update the packages and inform you.

Comment: Update: I reinstalled TeXLive from TUG and everything works fine!